# Adding URL to main.js in angular for kubernetes

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I am currently working on a project with mysql, springboot and angular(front-end) which I have to deploy on kubernetes. I have managed to get mysql and springboot to work by adding a service but I am not sure how to do with angular.
Here's my `springboot-deplyoment.yml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-service
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sample-service
        image: username/sample-service
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8091
        env:
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
          value: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/buddyto_mstr_local?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
          value: root
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          value: root
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8091
      targetPort: 8091
  selector:
    app: sample-service
  type: NodePort
```

Here's my `angular-deployment.yml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: angular
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: angular
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: angular
    spec:
      hostname: "sample-service"
      containers:
        - name: angular
          image: username/angular
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
          - name: BACKEND_BASE_URL
            value: http://sample-service:8091
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: angular
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: angular
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Here's my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx:alpine
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8091
COPY ./dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ARG BACKEND_BASE_URL=http://sample-service:8091
```

I want to connect angular to springboot but I am not sure what to add as a url in main.js before creating the docker image. I tried using `http://sample-service:8080` but it didn't work.